# IE8 throws Unspecified error when using Raphael text()

Tags: text, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I am using Raphaël 2.1.0. I draw several paths, circles, and rectangles, and everything seems to work fine on both IE9 (SVG) and IE8 (VML). However, when I try to add text to the canvas using [text](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text) function, IE8 always throws Unspecified error, and the error seems to be on this line, raphael.js, line 5179 character 13, which is

```
var brect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
```

I don't see any error on IE7 though. Does anyone has an idea what might be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code related to the `Paper.text(...)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think it might have something to do with IE9 developer tools or my browser. I couldn't reproduce the issue anymore.